# Need to conditionally apply function to every element in a character matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a table that only consists of numbers and "" (blank spaces). I need the numbers to be formatted using scientific notation. The issue is, is that if I make this matrix of a numeric type, then I can't use "" since it is not a number, but I need it to be a blank space. If I make this matrix of character type, then the 'scientific' function from the scales library does not recognize the numbers since they are numeric type. If I try to write an if statement within a for loop that iterates through every element in my matrix, then the condition is only applied to the first element generating the following error below:

> Error in if (moduleTraitPvalueSig != "") { : 
>    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (moduleTraitPvalueSig != "") { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I am using a matrix called moduleTraitPvalueSig, and the code that geneates the error above is as such

```
library(scales)
moduleTraitPvalueSig <- moduleTraitPvalue;
moduleTraitPvalueSig[moduleTraitPvalueSig>=0.05]<- ""
for(row in 1:nrow(moduleTraitPvalueSig)) {
  for(col in 1:ncol(moduleTraitPvalueSig)) {
    if(moduleTraitPvalueSig!="")
    {scientific(moduleTraitPvalueSig)}
  }
}
```

> Error in if (moduleTraitPvalueSig != "") { :
>
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In if (moduleTraitPvalueSig != "") { :
>
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Having blank spaces in a table is a matter for *printing* or *rendering* the table, not for calculating it. I suggest you keep the `NA` values in there, and convert them to empty spaces when you print/render it. "How" to do this depends on your rendering method.

Comment: Your loops of `i` and `j` are being completely ignored when you use `if(moduleTraitPvalueSig!="")`, since `moduleTraitPvalueSig` is referencing the entire object, not just the `[i,j]` element. Perhaps you meant `moduleTraitPvalueSig[i,j] != ""`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse number *use* and calculations with rendering. You shouldn't be worrying about scientific notation and spaces until you are ready to print/render.

Some sample data:

```
m <- matrix(pi, nr=3, nc=3)
m[1,2] <- m[2,3] <- NA
m
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 3.141593       NA 3.141593
# [2,] 3.141593 3.141593       NA
# [3,] 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593
```

You don't need a loop, just convert all at once.

```
m[] <- scales::scientific(m)
m
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
# [1,] "3.14e+00" "NA"       "3.14e+00"
# [2,] "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00" "NA"      
# [3,] "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00"
```

Unfortunately, `scale::scientific` cares not about `NA` (odd!), but that doesn't change things much for us, we can re-assign this way:

```
m[ m == "NA" ] <- ""
m
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
# [1,] "3.14e+00" ""         "3.14e+00"
# [2,] "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00" ""        
# [3,] "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00" "3.14e+00"
```

---

Other notes about your code/errors:

- `the condition has length > 1` is because `if (condition) { ... }` requires a condition of length precisely 1. Since you are comparing your whole object, it is returning a length (of `TRUE`/`FALSE`/`NA`) equal in length to the total dimensions of your object; that is, if your matrix is 3x5, then your `if` statement is being given 15 logicals. It takes only one, anything else is an error. Vectorizing if/else is done with `ifelse(cond, true_expr, false_expr)`, but that's a different story (and you do not need it at all here). There are countless questions on SO that reference this precise error message, I suggest you can do a bit more searching on it for more info.
- `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` is often related, given when the length of logical returns is 0 instead of 1 (expected) or more than 1 (the other error you received). This error as well is very frequent on SO, research will give you plenty of examples and ways to investigate/fix it.
- if you are going to do the matrix comparisons element-wise (very inefficient in R given what you intend to do), then at least you can use your `for` loop values. Using the `m` matrix I generated above, that would turn the code into something like:

  ```
  # you could use this in place of `m[ m == "NA" ] <- ""`
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(m))) {
      if (m[i,j] == "NA") m[i,j] == ""
    }
  }
  ```

  but please don't use it. If you do, don't say I told you to do that kind of replacement in this way, I'll lose what little credibility I've got :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to R so I wasn't sure how it worked under the hood. I do appreciate your clear explanations and up voted your answer but it doesn't show since I don't have enough SO reputation yet.